# If hackers know my android app license key , can they redirect the in app purchases of my app to their account?

Tags: android

I have published an android app with in app purchase. I failed to encrypt XOR my licence key. If hackers have my license key can they redirect my payments to their account or just they can by pass in app purchase ?

Answer (score 2):

Knowing your app key doesn't give any control over your developer account or payments, it is supposed to identify the app, AFAICT.

Also, XOR encryption in app code is merely obfuscation, a poor form of DRM.

If they can extract the key, they might also be able to locally manipulate the app to bypass restrictions on paid features.